# datetime exception

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

im getting exception while i am fatching the data from  the text-box of gridview

```
DateTime dt;
.
.
{

 dt = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form[row.FindControl("txtPLI_MAN").UniqueID]);
 // then i handel this to data base
```

but im getting exception over here that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

here is the exception detail

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
Message="String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Source="mscorlib"
StackTrace:
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles   styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
   at Newattendance.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\conversion\work_space\my_workspace.aspx.cs:line 61
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

where i am wrong how to get the date from text box properly

Comment: What does the offending date string look like? What culture is your thread running under?

Comment: 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM in this format

Comment: Does `DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM")` work? What is the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`? How do you want to deal with localization issues?

Comment: Oh, is `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM` what you have in the textbox, or what you have in `Request.Form[row.FindControl("txtPLI_MAN").UniqueID]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use a string and convert the string to datetime. 
like:

```
 string s="";
s=Request.Form[row.FindControl("txtPLI_MAN").UniqueID];
datetime dt;
dt=datetime.Parse(s);
```

or

```
dt=(datetime)s;
```

and see what happens

At least with this you can debug at each and every step to see the content and see where you are making a mistake

Comment: What's the difference in the first? I mean, besides the redundant initialization? The second fails to compile because you can't cast a string to DateTime.

Comment: Finally i got the date simply i do 
    dt = Request.Form[row.FindControl("txtPLI_MAN").UniqueID];
and dt is of string type only, no need to parse or typecast 

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine way to retrieve the value.  The error message says that the value is not in a format that it can convert to a string though.  That's the problem you need to investigate (not enough details given for us to really help)

An alternative way to get the value without Request.Form is to ask the control directly...

`dt = DateTime.Parse(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtPLI_MAN")).Text);`

This won't fix your parsing problem though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `row` denotes in your code and also `Request.form` isn't right place to look for the values at the time of post back.

I'll suggest you should include the button1 in all grid view row like: 
`<asp:button id="btn" runat="server commandname="doit" />`

and then implement Row_Command event of a grid in order to get data correctly from textbox.
check if the current command is "doit" by checking `e.CommandName=="doit"` and get your textbox from `e.Item.findControl`

I'm geussing you are not using above method from exception, since it says button1_click and you should not handle button click but handle row_command to get going with that.